# usort using a variable for column name

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how I can pass a variable into the below usort function to use as the array column name

```
usort($elements, function($a, $b, $sort_column) {
return $a[$sort_column] - $b[$sort_column];
});
```

I get the below error message

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for display_sorted_array::{closure}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `use` keyword:

```
usort($elements, function($a, $b) use ($sort_column) {
    return $a[$sort_column] - $b[$sort_column];
});
```

Comment: still getting error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sort_column' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in

Comment: @ManurajSebastian you have to wrap the imported variables from use in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The closure gets called by `usort()` and it will always be called with only the $a and $b vars.

you can however use the dreaded `global` keyword inside the fucntion and set the global variable before calling your usort like this:

```
$sort_column = 'whatever';
usort($elements, function($a, $b) {
      global $sort_column;
      return $a[$sort_column] - $b[$sort_column];
});
```

> leaving this up since it will show poeple considering this why not to but devon's answer is way better and should be used instead since it uses a langguage construct specific for this and isolates state better.